# What happens if my Node.js server crashes while waiting for web services callback?

Tags: node.js, web-services, transactions, soa

Im just starting to look into Node.js to create a web application that asynchrounously calls multiple web services to complete a single client request. I think in SOA speak this is known as a composite service / transaction.

My Node.js application will be responsible for completing any compensating actions should any web service calls fail within the composite service. For example, if service A and B return 'success', but service C returns 'fail', Node.js may need to apply a compensating action (undo effectively) on service A and B.

My question is, what if my Node.js server crashes? I could be in the middle of a composite transaction. Multiple calls to web services have been made, and I am waiting for the callbacks. If my node server crashes, responses meant for the callbacks will go unheard. It could then be possible that one of the web services was not successful, and that some compensating actions on other services would be needed.

Im not sure how I would be able to address this once my node server is back online. This could potentially put the system in an inconsistent state if service A and B succeeded, but C didn't.

Comment: It seems like you need to keep track of each composite transactions (request to A, B, C) independent of your node.js process.  This seems like a complicated problem but I think is solved in RDBMS https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributed transactions [are bad for SOA](http://arnon.me/2010/09/soa-antipattern-transactional-integration/) - they introduce dependency,rigidity , security and performance problems. You can implement a [Saga](http://www.rgoarchitects.com/Files/SOAPatterns/Saga.pdf) instead which means that each of your services will need to be aware of the on-going operation and take compensating actions if they find out there was a problem. You'd want to save state for each of the services so that they'd know on recovery to get to a consistent internal state.

If you find you must have distributed transactions than you should probably rethink the boundaries between your services.

(updates from the comments)
Even if you use a Saga, you may find that you want some coordinator to control the compensation - but if your services are autonomous they won't need that central coordinator -they'd perform the compensating action themselves - for example if they use the reservation pattern infoq.com/news/2009/09/reservations . They can perform compensation on expiration of the reservation. Otherwise, you can persist the state somewhere (redis/db/zookeeper etc.) and then check that on recovery of the coordinator

Comment: So what are you saying? All services should have boundaries around client requests (i.e. browser requests) that seems very un-SOA to me! Surely the biggest benefit of SOA is being able to solve business problems using multiple services. Udi Dahan talks a lot about composite UI and service composition http://www.udidahan.com/2014/07/30/service-oriented-composition-with-video/

Comment: I see two main patterns for UI integration http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/composite-frontend/ and http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/client-server-service/. The first variant is what you see on sites like linkedIn, Amazon etc.and then various parts of the UI are served by different services (e.g. recommendations, the main book info, ratings). The second kind looks similar but is more coupled . IMHO, for autonomy services should decide how to get to correct state without the need for a UI to get them there. You don't know if the user changes her mind, the server  crashor each of the services

Comment: So using composite fronted, you orchestrate services on the 'UI host' (as per your link). My question still stands: If my UI host crashes before it receives a response from the services and Service A and B succeeded but C didn't, how do I recover? i.e. how do I gain the knowledge of the failure on reboot, and then perform compensating actions

Comment: If your services are autonomous they won't need that -they'd perform the compensating action themselves - for example if they use the reservation pattern http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/09/reservations . They can perform compensation on expiration of the reservation. Otherwise you can persist the state somewhere (redis/db/zookeeper etc.) and then check that on recovery

Comment: Do you maybe want to update your answer with your comments? Will accept this answer then